# download the collection and import to mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I Try To Download Collection In MongoDB And Call The File Grade.json And Import It To Mongo/MongoDB.

[Link To Grade Collection](https://university.mongodb.com/static/MongoDB_2015_M101N_October/handouts/grades.ef42a2b3e7ff.json)

How Can I Do It???

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put the JSON file in a directory, **cd/ -into- that directory** then simply use `mongoimport`

```
mongoimport --db DATABASENAME --collection COLLECTIONNAME --type json --file YOURFILE.json --jsonArray
```

Sometimes that won't work, so you just need to supply your local `host`:

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --db DATABASENAME --collection COLLECTIONNAME --type json --file YOURFILE.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: but how i create this json file??

Comment: Just save it as whatever.json, easy as that!